# Automatically Copy a Screenshot to the Clipboard in Fedora (Linux)

Tags: linux, screenshot, copy-paste, fedora

I am Just Wondering if there is any possibility in Linux (Fedora) that When I Press the PrtSc Button to take a Screenshot, It Automatically Got Saved in my Clipboard, and I can paste it anywhere( Slack, WhatsApp Web, Mails etc, where pasting images is supported) until it is in my clipboard.

(This Already Happen in Windows, like when we press PrtSc Button, the Screenshot is Saved in Clipboard and I Can paste it places like Paint, WhatsApp Web, Slack, MS Word etc),

In Linux, It is Just Saving the Screenshots in Pictures Directly and I have to specially open and upload that image.

This Copying Pasting the Screenshot is Quit Handly and Simple,

If Anything like this is possible please help

Comment: There is a tool called Screenshot (at least in Ubuntu) that allows you to copy the image to the Clipboard. In my case it was preinstalled, but I'm pretty sure you can install it if you don't have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> for take screenshot to clipboard

[Take screenshots on fedora](https://fedoramagazine.org/take-screenshots-on-fedora/)

Comment: Thanks, This is What I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Windows user and want it to be just like on Windows (Shift + Windows Button + S) then this is how to set it up:

For Fedora 36:

1. Press the Windows Button (called "Super Key" in Linux)
2. Type "Keyboard" and hit enter
3. Go to the 2nd Menu called "Shortcut"
4. On the left side under categories open the dropdown for "System"
5. Click on "Screenshots and Recording"
6. In the "Keyboard shortcuts" field, select the second list item called "Copy a screenshot of an area to clipboard"
7. Below the "Keyboard shortcuts" field there is the field "Keyboard bindings"
8. To edit a keyboard binding, click it and press the new keys (backspace to clear it) --> the new Keys are the Keys you are using under Windows
9. Done: when entering the shortcut you can now take a screenshot that is automatically copied to your clipboard

Let me know if you encounter any issues with this description